# Bootstrap not being applied to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, live

I'm attempting to make a calculator where you have the possibility to increase the number of inputs if you so wish to - the calculator itself works fine in finding the necessary values, however I wish to also have the possibility to search through the dropdown inputs as they do get quite lengthy, hence why I am using [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/).

The problem is that only the default inputs get the bootstrap theme applied to them, whereas the inputs created by clicking on the necessary button don't get the theme applied. How do I go about fixing this?

**What do you expect?** All inputs to be 'stylised' like the default one, with the search menu etc.
**What do you get?** Only the default input is 'stylised', whereas the ones created by clicking on the button don't

```js
var i = 0;

function createGear() {
    i++;
    
    var container = document.getElementById("newGear");
    
    var gear = document.createElement("select");
    gear.id = "gear" + i;
    gear.setAttribute("class", "selectpicker");
    gear.setAttribute("data-live-search", "true");
    container.appendChild(gear);
    
    
    
    var none = document.createElement("option");
    none.value = "none";
    none.text = "";
    gear.add(none);
    
    
    
    
    var pistols = document.createElement("optgroup");
    pistols.label = "Pistols";
    gear.add(pistols);
    
    
    
    
    var pistol1 = document.createElement("option");
    pistol1.value = "pistol1";
    pistol1.text = "M1911";
    gear.add(pistol1);
    pistols.appendChild(pistol1);
    
    return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="gear0">
                <option></option>
                <optgroup label="Pistols">
                    <option value="pistol1">M1911</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
        <div id="newGear">
            
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="createGear()" value="Create Gear Input!"> 
    </form>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `select` that you dynamically add to the page are never initialised as `bootstrap-select` components. The one that you've already got on the page is automatically initialised as such when the page loads because it has the `selectpicker` class.

You just need to add this statement after you add the new select to the page:

```
$(gear).selectpicker();
```

Comment: Adding your code makes it work, however now the calculator aspect doesn't work - is there a way I can add this line of code outside of this specific function, so that components are initialised on ANY button click instead of with this specific one? I think it's messing up with the values of the input. You can see how I'm calculating the total value here: jsfiddle.net/Antarni/uhxg4178/

Comment: @AntArni I think that the problem is that you're calculation function uses `newGear.children[ix]` (child of `#newGear` at specific index) and `bootstrap-select` generates a lot of new elements and adds them to the same parent as the original `select` element.

Comment: Crap... how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Also I've noticed that the calculation still works for the 'default' input, however the calculator stops working once you add any more inputs - what could that mean?

Comment: @AntArni Your old `newGear.children[ix]` can be translated to `$("#newGear select")[ix]` or `document.querySelectorAll("#newGear select")[ix]`

Comment: Now I get a NaN result - maybe I've written it down wrong? jsfiddle.net/Antarni/re1e9wxb/

Comment: @AntArni No, it was a mistake on my part, I haven't considered the loop's condition, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/j5rnwa4t/

Comment: Well that's certainly better - now after creating elements, it still uses the values of the original into the calculation, but ignores the new elements. A more detailed version of mine (still relatively simple though): http://jsfiddle.net/Antarni/j5rnwa4t/1/

Comment: My bad, sent you an unfinished one: jsfiddle.net/uhxg4178/1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var gearPrices= new Array();
gearPrices["none"]=0;
gearPrices["pistol1"]=25000;

var i = 0;

function createGear() {
    i++;
    
    var container = document.getElementById("newGear");
    container.setAttribute("class", "bootstrap-select");
    
    var gear = document.createElement("select");
    gear.id = "gear" + i;
    gear.setAttribute("class", "selectpicker");
    gear.setAttribute("data-live-search", "true");
    container.appendChild(gear);
    
    
    
    var none = document.createElement("option");
    none.value = "none";
    none.text = "";
    gear.add(none);
    
    
    
    
    var pistols = document.createElement("optgroup");
    pistols.label = "Pistols";
    gear.add(pistols);
    
    
    
    
    var pistol1 = document.createElement("option");
    pistol1.value = "pistol1";
    pistol1.text = "M1911";
    gear.add(pistol1);
    pistols.appendChild(pistol1);
    
    var amount = document.createElement("input");
    amount.id = "amount" + i;
    amount.type = "number";
    container.appendChild(amount);
  
  // The newly created element should be updated
  $(gear).selectpicker('refresh');

    return i;
}

function getGearPrice() {
    var price = 0, ix, ixLen, value, type;
    var newGear = document.getElementById('newGear');
    
    price += (gearPrices[document.getElementById('gear0').value || 'none']) *     
             (document.getElementById('amount0').value || 0);
             
    var amountInputs = document.querySelectorAll("#newGear input[type='number']");
    var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll("#newGear select");
    
    for(ix = 0, ixLen = selectElements.length; ix < ixLen; ix++){
        type = selectElements[ix].value || 'none';
        value = amountInputs[ix].value || 0;
        price += gearPrices[type] * +value;
    }
    
    return price;
}

function getTotal() {
    var gearPrice = getGearPrice();
    
    document.getElementById('gearTotal').innerHTML = "Gear: £" + gearPrice;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="gear0">
                <option></option>
                <optgroup label="Pistols">
                    <option value="pistol1">M1911</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="amount0">
        <div id="newGear">
        
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="createGear()" value="Create Gear Input!">
        <input type="button" onClick="getTotal()">
    </form>
    <p id="gearTotal">
    Gear Total Over Here!
    </p>
    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  
  
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I had a feeling that the reason it wasn't working was because the bootstrap scripts were only run on page reload, hence why only the default values had it. How would I write this in plain javascript? I know practically zinch about jquery and I want to keep the javascript readable by me. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Adding your code makes it work, however now the calculator aspect doesn't work - is there a way I can add this line of code outside of this specific function, so that components are initialised on ANY button click instead of with this specific one? I think it's messing up with the values of the input. You can see how I'm calculating the total value here: jsfiddle.net/Antarni/uhxg4178/

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out and you should avoid usin `new Array()`;

Answer (score 0):

Please check if my solution is what you need. I add `{$('#' + gear.id).selectpicker();` cause for dynamically generated you have to call `bootstrap-select` manually. I also wrapped it in `setTimeout` to allow browser to render everything properly: `setTimeout(function () {$('#' + gear.id).selectpicker();}, 300)`.

```js
var i = 0;

function createGear() {
    i++;
    
    var container = document.getElementById("newGear");
    
    var gear = document.createElement("select");
    gear.id = "gear" + i;
    gear.setAttribute("class", "selectpicker");
    gear.setAttribute("data-live-search", "true");
    container.appendChild(gear);
    setTimeout(function () {$('#' + gear.id).selectpicker();}, 300)
    
    
    
    
    var none = document.createElement("option");
    none.value = "none";
    none.text = "";
    gear.add(none);
    
    
    
    
    var pistols = document.createElement("optgroup");
    pistols.label = "Pistols";
    gear.add(pistols);
    
    
    
    
    var pistol1 = document.createElement("option");
    pistol1.value = "pistol1";
    pistol1.text = "M1911";
    gear.add(pistol1);
    pistols.appendChild(pistol1);
    
    return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="gear0">
                <option></option>
                <optgroup label="Pistols">
                    <option value="pistol1">M1911</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
        <div id="newGear">
            
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="createGear()" value="Create Gear Input!"> 
    </form>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```